# LinkedIn API /adCampaigns returns "Unpermitted fields present in PARAMETER"

Tags: linkedin-api

From linkedIn's own documented example here

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/account-structure/create-and-manage-campaigns?view=li-lms-2022-07&tabs=http#search-for-campaigns

Request headers:

```
Authorization: 'Bearer <redacted>',
'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
'Linkedin-Version': '202206',
```

Request Url:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adCampaigns?q=search&search.type.values[0]=SPONSORED_UPDATES&search.status.values[0]=ACTIVE&sort.field=ID&sort.order=DESCENDING
```

Returns:
HTTP code 403 with this error:

```json
data: {
  serviceErrorCode: 100,
  code: 'ACCESS_DENIED',
  message: 'Unpermitted fields present in PARAMETER: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/search.status.values[0], /sort.field, /sort.order]'
}
```

I am confident my access token is ok as the request works using protocol v1.0.
app has the following permissions

- r_organization_social
- rw_organization_admin
- r_1st_connections_size
- r_organization_admin
- r_ads_reporting r_emailaddress r_liteprofile
- r_basicprofile
- r_ads
- rw_ads
- w_member_social
- w_organization_social

Answer (score 0):

I had to REMOVE the Restli header, then it worked:

```
'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0'
```